# Prisma relation multiple reference on the same model on prismaClient().model.delete()

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm having trouble deleting a record on my database and I'm having this kind of Error

```
Invalid `prisma.salesInvoice.delete()` invocation:


The change you are trying to make would violate the required relation 'pmrEmployee' between the `SalesInvoice` and `Employee` models.
```

Here is my model on my schema.prisma file

```
model Employee {
  id               String          @id @default(uuid())
  employeeInfo     EmployeeInfo    @relation(fields: [employeeInfoId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  employeeInfoId   String
  SalesInvoice     SalesInvoice?   @relation(fields: [SalesInvoiceId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  SalesInvoiceId   String?
  DeliveryRecipt   DeliveryRecipt? @relation(fields: [DeliveryReciptId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  DeliveryReciptId String?

  SIPmr        SalesInvoice[]   @relation(name: "pmrEmployee")
  DRPmr        DeliveryRecipt[] @relation(name: "DRpmrEmployee")
  SIPreparedBy SalesInvoice[]   @relation(name: "preparedByEmployee")
  DRPreparedBy DeliveryRecipt[] @relation(name: "preparedByEmployee")

  @@index([SalesInvoiceId])
  @@index([DeliveryReciptId])
  @@index([employeeInfoId])

}

model SalesInvoice {
  id                 String  @id @default(uuid())
  salesInvoiceNumber String  @unique
  dateIssued         String
  totalAmount        Decimal
  term               Int
  discount           Float?
  VAT                Decimal
  remarks            String? @db.VarChar(500)

  balance    Decimal @default(0)
  payables   Decimal @default(0)
  amountPaid Decimal @default(0)

  stockIn   Boolean @default(false)
  isPullout Boolean @default(false)
  isPaid    Boolean @default(false)
  isRemote  Boolean @default(true)

  pmr                Employee?        @relation(name: "pmrEmployee", fields: [pmrEmployeeId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  pmrEmployeeId      String?
  preparedBy         Employee?        @relation(name: "preparedByEmployee", fields: [preparedById], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  preparedById       String?
  client             Client?          @relation(name: "Client", fields: [clientId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  clientId           String?
  salesItemSummary   ItemSummary?     @relation(fields: [salesItemSummaryId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  salesItemSummaryId String?
  proofOfDelivery    proofOfDelivery? @relation(fields: [proofOfDeliveryId], references: [id])
  proofOfDeliveryId  String?

  Employee     Employee[]
  items        Item[]
  Client       Client[]
  monthlySales monthlySales[]
  PullOutItem  PullOutItem[]
  ItemSummary  ItemSummary[]  @relation(name: "salesInvoice" )
  TotalDetails TotalDetails?
  PaymentInfo  PaymentInfo[]

  @@index([pmrEmployeeId])
  @@index([preparedById])
  @@index([clientId])
  @@index([salesItemSummaryId])
  @@index([proofOfDeliveryId])


}
```

and this id my code for deleting such record

```js
export async function deleteInvoice(id: string): Promise<Status> {
  try {
    const invoice = await fetchSalesInvoiceById(id);

    const res = await prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
      if (!invoice) throw new Error("There are no records for this.");


      await tx.salesInvoice.delete({
        where: { id: invoice.id },
      });
    });

    await prisma.$disconnect();
    return {
      success: true,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      return {
        success: false,
        message: error.message,
      };
    }
    return {
      success: false,
      message: "There was some Error",
    };
  }
}
```

it works before I introduced the prisma relation mode I'm still in development so it's not really a big deal if I want to go back to foreign keys but I really wanted to use the relation mode on prisma

I did try to change my Employee model to be

```
model Employee {
  id               String          @id @default(uuid())
  employeeInfo     EmployeeInfo    @relation(fields: [employeeInfoId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  employeeInfoId   String
  SalesInvoice     SalesInvoice?   @relation(fields: [SalesInvoiceId], references: [id], onDelete: No Action, onUpdate: NoAction)
  SalesInvoiceId   String?
  DeliveryRecipt   DeliveryRecipt? @relation(fields: [DeliveryReciptId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  DeliveryReciptId String?

  SIPmr        SalesInvoice[]   @relation(name: "pmrEmployee")
  DRPmr        DeliveryRecipt[] @relation(name: "DRpmrEmployee")
  SIPreparedBy SalesInvoice[]   @relation(name: "preparedByEmployee")
  DRPreparedBy DeliveryRecipt[] @relation(name: "preparedByEmployee")

  @@index([SalesInvoiceId])
  @@index([DeliveryReciptId])
  @@index([employeeInfoId])

}
```

to be like this replacing to NoAction instead of Cascade but to no avail. Is there any workaround on this sort of problem or am I using this package wrong?